# Spring Boot: how to connect to external h2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I have created one Spring boot application and I am not using in-memory H2 database, instead I have installed exe for H2 database and using it externally. Now I want to connect my Spring boot app with this external H2 database. I have added the dependencies, I have added all the required properties in application.properties file **(you can see below**). Also I have created one Entity class having `@Entity` annotation. But when I am trying to connect with the database it is connecting even with different URL and username and I cannot see my Entity class table over there. So where am I doing a mistake and what are the things which I have missed, please address me on this.

For your information, my Spring boot app is running on port - 8080 and H2 database is running on 8082

```
 spring.h2.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver

 spring.h2.url = jdbc:h2:file:~/test2;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE; AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE

 spring.h2.username = QW

 spring.h2.password = root

 spring.h2.console.enabled = true

 spring.datasource.platform = h2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8082/~/<DB-NAME>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

Give in properties file

```
# H2
spring.datasource.url=<your value
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial below link

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/h2-database-example/
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database